# ST Monad == code smell?

Tags: haskell, state, monads, state-monad

I'm working on implementing the [UCT](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.102.1296) algorithm in Haskell, which requires a fair amount of data juggling.  Without getting into too much detail, it's a simulation algorithm where, at each "step," a leaf node in the search tree is selected based on some statistical properties, a new child node is constructed at that leaf, and the stats corresponding to the new leaf and all of its ancestors are updated.

Given all that juggling, I'm not really sharp enough to figure out how to make the whole search tree a nice immutable data structure à la [Okasaki](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf).  Instead, I've been playing around with the `ST` monad a bit, creating structures composed of mutable `STRef`s.  A contrived example (unrelated to UCT):

```hs
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef

data STRefPair s a b = STRefPair { left :: STRef s a, right :: STRef s b }

mkStRefPair :: a -> b -> ST s (STRefPair s a b)
mkStRefPair a b = do
    a' <- newSTRef a
    b' <- newSTRef b
    return $ STRefPair a' b'

derp :: (Num a, Num b) => STRefPair s a b -> ST s ()
derp p = do
    modifySTRef (left p) (\x -> x + 1)
    modifySTRef (right p) (\x -> x - 1)

herp :: (Num a, Num b) => (a, b)
herp = runST $ do
    p <- mkStRefPair 0 0
    replicateM_ 10 $ derp p
    a <- readSTRef $ left p
    b <- readSTRef $ right p
    return (a, b)

main = print herp -- should print (10, -10)
```

Obviously this particular example would be much easier to write without using `ST`, but hopefully it's clear where I'm going with this...  if I were to apply this sort of style to my UCT use case, is that wrong-headed?

Somebody asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607830/use-of-haskell-state-monad-a-code-smell) here a couple years back, but I think my question is a bit different...  I have no problem using monads to encapsulate mutable state when appropriate, but it's that "when appropriate" clause that gets me.  I'm worried that I'm reverting to an object-oriented mindset prematurely, where I have a bunch of objects with getters and setters.  Not exactly idiomatic Haskell...

On the other hand, if it *is* a reasonable coding style for some set of problems, I guess my question becomes: are there any well-known ways to keep this kind of code readable and maintainable?  I'm sort of grossed out by all the explicit reads and writes, and especially grossed out by having to translate from my `STRef`-based structures inside the `ST` monad to isomorphic but immutable structures outside.

Comment: "reasonable" is isomorphic to `time ∩ budget`

Comment: Minor point: you can use `liftM2`: `mkStRefPair a b = liftM2 STRefPair (newSTRef a) (newSTRef b)`, `liftM2 (,) (readSTRef $ left p) (readSTRef $ right p)`

Comment: Ahh @sdcvvc very nice.  For some reason it didn't occur to me that I could use `liftM2` on data constructors.

Comment: Just translating the algorithm from mutable to immutable should be straightforward enough: anywhere you would perform an update in the mutable algorithm, return an updated version of the entire datastructure instead. The hard part is making it performant (mainly by maximizing sharing). But you probably knew this. Given that the whole point of an algorithm like this is performance and (minimizing) time complexity, I suppose this observation isn't very helpful. :)

Comment: This is in reply to the bounty query -- I don't think there *is* a good rule other than "use `ST` when you need mutation" and "you need mutation when the algorithm demands mutation to preserve complexity bounds" and "decide if the algorithm needs mutation to preserve complexity bounds by analyzing the algorithm."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of Haskell state monad a code smell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607830/use-of-haskell-state-monad-a-code-smell)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I don't use ST much, but sometimes it is just the best solution. This can be in many scenarios:

- There are already well-known, efficient ways to solve a problem. Quicksort is a perfect example of this. It is known for its speed and in-place behavior, which cannot be imitated by pure code very well.
- You need rigid time and space bounds. Especially with lazy evaluation (and Haskell doesn't even specify whether there is lazy evaluation, just that it is non-strict), the behavior of your programs can be very unpredictable. Whether there is a memory leak could depend on whether a certain optimization is enabled. This is very different from imperative code, which has a fixed set of variables (usually) and defined evaluation order.
- You've got a deadline. Although the pure style is almost always better practice and cleaner code, if you are used to writing imperatively and need the code soon, starting imperative and moving to functional later is a perfectly reasonable choice.

When I do use ST (and other monads), I try to follow these general guidelines:

- Use [Applicative](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html) style often. This makes the code easier to read and, if you do switch to an immutable version, much easier to convert. Not only that, but Applicative style is much more compact.
- Don't just use ST. If you program only in ST, the result will be no better than a huge C program, possibly worse because of the explicit reads and writes. Instead, intersperse pure Haskell code where it applies. I often find myself using things like `STRef s (Map k [v])`. The map itself is being mutated, but much of the heavy lifting is done purely.
- Don't remake libraries if you don't have to. A lot of code written for IO can be cleanly, and fairly mechanically, converted to ST. Replacing all the `IORef`s with `STRef`s and `IO`s with `ST`s in Data.HashTable was much easier than writing a hand-coded hash table implementation would have been, and probably faster too.

One last note - if you are having trouble with the explicit reads and writes, there are [ways around it](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2007/08/programming-in-c-ummm-haskell-heres.html).

Comment: Amusingly enough, the "ways around it" link is a post written by @augustss, who wrote an answer to this question that I didn't find useful :P  Ironic.  Very cool though, and good motivation to check out `Applicative`.  I've heard good things about it :)

Comment: I'd give this answer +5 if I could.  I'm glad to see you got the bounty.  The fact is, imperative code is not a scourge to be avoided at all costs; it's just much less nice to work on than functional code.  Functional programming is a wonderful abstraction, but it is only that - computers are machines whose fundamental mode of operation is _doing things one after another_.  When a task is easily (or already) correctly solved by an imperative program, there is no good reason to throw that solution out, especially when ST can even prove for us that it has a pure interface.

Comment: I'm not sure quicksort is such a great example: it could be useful if you were already using mutable arrays for another reason, but for just sorting a list it's no faster than `Data.List.sort`

Comment: @JeremyList - quicksort is badly named, which leads to confusion.  It isn't particularly fast, all things considered.  But it *is* an in-place algorithm, which means that it uses half as much memory as just about every other sort algorithm you'll come across, including `Data.List.sort` which is a (heavily optimized version of) mergesort.

Answer (score 11):

Algorithms which make use of mutation and algorithms which do not are different algorithms. Sometimes there is a strightforward bounds-preserving translation from the former to the latter, sometimes a difficult one, and sometimes only one which does not preserve complexity bounds.

A skim of the paper reveals to me that I don't think it makes essential use of mutation -- and so I think a potentially really nifty lazy functional algorithm could be developed. But it would be a different but related algorithm to that described.

Below, I describe one such approach -- not necessarily the best or most clever, but pretty straightforward:

Here's the setup a I understand it -- A) a branching tree is constructed B) payoffs are then pushed back from the leafs to the root which then indicates the best choice at any given step. *But* this is expensive, so instead, only portions of the tree are explored to the leafs in a nondeterministic manner. Furthermore, each further exploration of the tree is determined by what's been learned in previous explorations.

So we build code to describe the "stage-wise" tree. Then, we have another data structure to define a partially explored tree along with partial reward estimates. We then have a function of `randseed -> ptree -> ptree` that given a random seed and a partially explored tree, embarks on one further exploration of the tree, updating the ptree structure as we go. Then, we can just iterate this function over an empty seed ptree to get a list of increasingly more sampled spaces in the ptree. We then can walk this list until some specified cutoff condition is met.

So now we've gone from one algorithm where everything is blended together to three distinct steps -- 1) building the whole state tree, lazily, 2) updating some partial exploration with some sampling of a structure and 3) deciding when we've gathered enough samples.

Comment: The issue I'm having, I think, is with the implementation of `ptree`.  It's pretty hefty.  Each non-leaf node in the tree is a "multi-armed bandit" and every child of such a node is an "arm."  You always play the arm with the greatest UCB1 value among its siblings, and any time any arm of a bandit is played, the UCB1 values of *all* arms of that bandit change...  I suspect you're right: there probably is a slick way to implement this using immutable data structures without compromising complexity bounds, but my point is that I'm not clever enough to figure it out.

Comment: @mergeconflict -- so you have `PTreeNode [(UCB1,PTreeNode)]` ? -- i.e. just store the UCB1s with the nodes rather than inside the nodes?

Comment: Be aware that the cost of creating a new, immutable tree isn't the cost of copying *all* the nodes, just the spine leading to the updated nodes and the new nodes.  That is, the ghc runtime uses mutability under the hood; an immutable solution might be more performant than you're imagining.  At any rate, I'd get the immutable version working correctly, then if it's too slow, add the ST.

Answer (score 9):

It's can be really difficult to tell when using ST is appropriate.  I would suggest you do it with ST and without ST (not necessarily in that order).  Keep the non-ST version simple; using ST should be seen as an optimization, and you don't want to do that until you know you need it.

Comment: So, uh...  Any examples where you've faced a similar choice?  Anything you've learned about how to keep this style of code clean?

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit that I cannot read the Haskell code. But if you use ST for mutating the tree, then you can probably replace this with an immutable tree without losing much because:

## Same complexity for mutable and immutable tree

You have to mutate every node above the new leaf. An immutable tree has to replace all nodes above the modified node. So in both cases the touched nodes are the same, thus you don't gain anything in complexity.

For e.g. Java object creation is more expensive than mutation, so maybe you can gain a bit here in Haskell by using mutation. But this I don't know for sure. But a small gain does not buy you much because of the next point.

## Updating the tree is presumably not the bottleneck

The evaluation of the new leaf will probably be much more expensive than updating the tree. At least this is the case for UCT in computer Go.

Comment: This is only true for single operations.

Comment: @dan_waterworth It's true for trees, arrays are different.

Answer (score 2):

Use of the ST monad is usually (but not always) as an optimization. For any optimization, I apply the same procedure:

1. Write the code without it,
2. Profile and identify bottlenecks,
3. Incrementally rewrite the bottlenecks and test for improvements/regressions,

The other use case I know of is as an alternative to the state monad. The key difference being that with the state monad the type of all of the data stored is specified in a top-down way, whereas with the ST monad it is specified bottom-up. There are cases where this is useful.

Comment: That's why just about every time I've ever used `ST` it hasn't been `ST` it's been `ReaderT <structure full of STRefs> ST`