# Applicative instance for State and other MTL monads?

Tags: haskell, state-monad, applicative

Looking at the docs for [`Control.Applicative`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html), I notice that they have instance declarations for certain monads (e.g. `IO`, `Maybe` and notably `ST`), but there are no instances for MTL monads such as `State` and `RWS`.  Instead it looks like there's a general-purpose [`WrappedMonad`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html#t:WrappedMonad) type defined, which I'm guessing is to cover all other cases.

So here are my questions:

1. Why aren't there `Applicative` instances for MTL monads?  The best answer I've been able to find on my own so far is a [three year old post](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2316), where somebody implemented these instances and was summarily ignored.
2. What's the deal with `WrappedMonad`?  I found a [post on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/d8can/an_overview_of_the_standard_type_classes/c0yfd0i) that explains it briefly, but I think I'm confused about how to use it.

Ultimately I'd like to be able to use `State` in an applicative style (as was [recommended to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880555/st-monad-code-smell)), but if I have to litter my code with `WrappedMonad` data constructors then it doesn't seem like a win.  I could also ignore `WrappedMonad` entirely, and define the `Applicative` instance myself the same way that was done for `IO`, `ST` and so on: in terms of `return` and `ap`...  But that seems goofy as well.

Comment: If only we had Functor => Applicative => Monad, and (Alternative, Monad) => MonadPlus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That documentation is generated based solely on the contents of the `base` package, which does not contain `State` - so it does not contain `Applicative` instances for it.  If you look in [the MTL documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t%3aStateT), you'll see an `Applicative` instance listed.

Alternately, you can open up GHCi, import Control.Monad.State and Control.Applicative, and use `:i Applicative` to list the instances of `Applicative` or `:i StateT` to list the classes for which `StateT` has instances (`State` is a type alias for `StateT` with one of its parameters fixed).  Either will show that there is indeed such an instance.

Comment: Evidently I'm blind as a bat.  I was looking at that exact documentation and didn't see the `Applicative` instance.

Answer (score 2):

The Applicative instances for the mtl monads can't be listed in the base docs, because there's no mtl available at that point. The good news is that mtl has Applicative instances [StateT for example](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t%3aStateT), since mtl-2.0.0.0.