# Can a `ST`-like monad be executed purely (without the `ST` library)?

Tags: haskell, state, monads, ghc, purely-functional

This post is literate Haskell. Just put in a file like "pad.lhs" and `ghci` will be able to run it.

```
> {-# LANGUAGE GADTs, Rank2Types #-}
> import Control.Monad
> import Control.Monad.ST
> import Data.STRef
```

Okay, so I was able to figure how to represent the `ST` monad in pure code. First we start with our reference type. Its specific value is not really important. The most important thing is that `PT s a` should not be isomorphic to any other type `forall s`. (In particular, it should be isomorphic to neither `()` nor `Void`.)

```
> newtype PTRef s a = Ref {unref :: s a} -- This is defined liked this to make `toST'` work. It may be given a different definition.
```

The kind for `s` is `*->*`, but that is not really important right now. It could be [polykind](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism.html), for all we care.

```
> data PT s a where
>     MkRef   :: a -> PT s (PTRef s a)
>     GetRef  :: PTRef s a -> PT s a
>     PutRef  :: a -> PTRef s a -> PT s ()
>     AndThen :: PT s a -> (a -> PT s b) -> PT s b
```

Pretty straight forward. `AndThen` allows us to use this as a `Monad`. You may be wondering how `return` is implemented. Here is its monad instance (it only respects monad laws with respect to `runPF`, to be defined later):

```
> instance Monad (PT s) where
>     (>>=)    = AndThen
>     return a = AndThen (MkRef a) GetRef --Sorry. I like minimalism.
> instance Functor (PT s) where
>     fmap = liftM
> instance Applicative (PT s) where
>     pure  = return
>     (<*>) = ap
```

Now we can define `fib` as a test case.

```
> fib :: Int -> PT s Integer
> fib n = do
>     rold <- MkRef 0
>     rnew <- MkRef 1
>     replicateM_ n $ do
>         old <- GetRef rold
>         new <- GetRef rnew
>         PutRef      new  rold
>         PutRef (old+new) rnew
>     GetRef rold
```

And it type checks. Hurray! Now, I was able to convert this to `ST` (we now see why `s` had to be `* -> *`)

```
> toST :: PT (STRef s) a -> ST s a
> toST (MkRef  a        ) = fmap Ref $ newSTRef a
> toST (GetRef   (Ref r)) = readSTRef r
> toST (PutRef a (Ref r)) = writeSTRef r a
> toST (pa `AndThen` apb) = (toST pa) >>= (toST . apb)
```

Now we can define a function to run `PT` without referencing `ST` at all:

```
> runPF :: (forall s. PT s a) -> a
> runPF p = runST $ toST p
```

`runPF $ fib 7` gives `13`, which is correct.

---

### My question is can we define `runPF` without reference using `ST` at all?

Is there a pure way to define `runPF`? `PTRef`'s definition is completely unimportant; it's only a placeholder type anyway. It can be redefined to whatever makes it work.

If you *cannot* define `runPF` purely, give a proof that it cannot.

Performance is not a concern (if it was, I would not have made every `return` have its own ref).

I'm thinking that existential types may be useful.

Note: It's trivial if we assume is `a` is dynamicable or something. I'm looking for an answer that works with all `a`.

Note: In fact, an answer does not even necessarily have much to do with `PT`. It just needs to be as powerful as `ST` without using magic. (Conversion from `(forall s. PT s)` is sort of a test of if an answer is valid or not.)

Comment: You could let `s ~ Const Int` in `runPF` and keep a `Map` with `Int` keys and `a` values.

Comment: Can we assume `Typeable a` in each `PT s a`? If so, it's a matter of adapting [IOSpec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/IOSpec), I guess.

Comment: Or even more simply, if everything is `Typeable`, a `Map Int Dynamic` should suffice to represent the `STRef`s backstore. Reads/writes will need to be implemented through partial (but pure) functions, in that case.

Comment: @chi That makes it too easy.

Comment: Perhaps with [dependent-map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-map-0.2.0.1), then one could define the store. AFAICS, that package uses to casts from `Dynamic` or `Typeable`-style casts (not so sure about this, just did a quick scan of the source, only). A `GCompare` instance is needed, but only on the keys (refs), and we can provide it, I think.

Comment: @DavidYoung Not all refs contain `a`s.

Comment: The closest I know of is Andrea Vezzosi's safe ST monad in Agda.

http://code.haskell.org/~Saizan/ST/ST.agda

My understanding is that in Haskell you need to compromise on one of 3 things without using out of the box ST: Either a.) you need a simpler universe of ref types, e.g. Typeable, b.) you need to accept unsafeCoerce, or c.) you need to use some form of an indexed monad.

Answer (score 14):

tl;dr: It's not possible without adjustments to the definition of `PT`. Here's the core problem: you'll be running your stateful computation in the context of some sort of storage medium, but said storage medium has to know how to store *arbitrary* types. This isn't possible without packaging up some sort of evidence into the `MkRef` constructor - either an existentially wrapped `Typeable` dictionary as others have suggested, or a proof that the value belongs to one of a known finite set of types.

For a first attempt, let's try using a list as the storage medium and integers to refer to elements of the list.

```
newtype Ix a = MkIx Int  -- the index of an element in a list

interp :: PT Ix a -> State [b] a
interp (MkRef x) = modify (++ [x]) >> gets (Ref . MkIx . length)
-- ...
```

When storing a new item in the environment, we make sure to add it to the end of the list, so that `Ref`s we've previously given out stay pointing at the correct element.

This ain't right. I can make a reference to *any* type `a`, but the type of `interp` says that the storage medium is a homogeneous list of `b`s. GHC has us bang to rights when it rejects this type signature, complaining that it can't match `b` with the type of the thing inside `MkRef`.

---

Undeterred, let us have a go at using a *heterogeneous* list as the environment for the `State` monad in which we'll interpret `PT`.

```
infixr 4 :>
data Tuple as where
    E :: Tuple '[]
    (:>) :: a -> Tuple as -> Tuple (a ': as)
```

This is one of my personal favourite Haskell data types. It's an *extensible tuple* indexed by a list of the types of the things inside it. Tuples are heterogeneous linked lists with type-level information about the types of the things inside it. (It's often called `HList` following [Kiselyov's paper](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/HList-ext.pdf) but I prefer `Tuple`.) When you add something to the front of a tuple, you add its type to the front of the list of types. In a poetic mood, [I once put it this way](https://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/issue24.pdf): "The tuple and its type grow together, like a vine creeping up a bamboo plant."

Examples of `Tuple`s:

```
ghci> :t 'x' :> E
'x' :> E :: Tuple '[Char]
ghci> :t "hello" :> True :> E
"hello" :> True :> E :: Tuple '[[Char], Bool]
```

What do references to values inside tuples look like? We have to prove to GHC that the type of the thing we're getting out of the tuple is indeed the type we expect.

```
data Elem as a where  -- order of indices arranged for convenient partial application
    Here :: Elem (a ': as) a
    There :: Elem as a -> Elem (b ': as) a
```

The definition of `Elem` is structurally that of the natural numbers (`Elem` values like `There (There Here)` look similar to natural numbers like `S (S Z)`) but with extra types - in this case, proving that the type `a` is in the type-level list `as`. I mention this because it's suggestive: `Nat`s make good list indices, and likewise `Elem` is useful for indexing into a tuple. In this respect it'll be useful as a replacement for the `Int` inside our reference type.

```
(!) :: Tuple as -> Elem as a -> a
(x :> xs) ! Here = x
(x :> xs) ! (There ix) = xs ! ix
```

We need a couple of functions to work with tuples and indices.

```
type family as :++: bs where
    '[] :++: bs = bs
    (a ': as) :++: bs = a ': (as :++: bs)

appendT :: a -> Tuple as -> (Tuple (as :++: '[a]), Elem (as :++: '[a]) a)
appendT x E = (x :> E, Here)
appendT x (y :> ys) = let (t, ix) = appendT x ys
                      in (y :> t, There ix)
```

Let's try and write an interpreter for a `PT` in a `Tuple` environment.

```
interp :: PT (Elem as) a -> State (Tuple as) a
interp (MkRef x) = do
    t <- get
    let (newT, el) = appendT x t
    put newT
    return el
-- ...
```

No can do, buster. The problem is that the type of the `Tuple` in the environment changes when we obtain a new reference. As I mentioned before, adding something to a tuple adds its type to the tuple's type, a fact belied by the type `State (Tuple as) a`. GHC's not fooled by this attempted subterfuge: `Could not deduce (as ~ (as :++: '[a1]))`.

---

This is where the wheels come off, as far as I can tell. What you really want to do is keep the size of the tuple constant throughout a `PT` computation. This would require you to index `PT` itself by the list of types to which you can obtain references, proving every time you do so that you're allowed to (by giving an `Elem` value). The environment would then look like a tuple of lists, and a reference would consist an `Elem` (to select the right list) and an `Int` (to find the particular item in the list).

This plan breaks the rules, of course (you need to change the definition of `PT`), but it also has engineering problems. When I call `MkRef`, the onus is on me to give an `Elem` for the value I'm making a reference to, which is pretty tedious. (That said, you can usually convince GHC to find `Elem` values by proof search using a hacky type class.)

Another thing: composing `PT`s becomes difficult. All the parts of your computation have to be indexed by the *same* list of types. You could attempt to introduce combinators or classes which allow you to grow the environment of a `PT`, but you'd also have to update all the references when you do that. Using the monad would be quite difficult.

A possibly-cleaner implementation would allow the list of types in a `PT` to vary as you walk around the datatype: every time you encounter a `MkRef` the type gets one longer. Because the type of the computation changes as it progresses, you can't use a regular monad - you have to resort to [`IxMonad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/indexed-0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Indexed.html) . If you want to know what that program looks like, see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33977350/1523776).

Ultimately, the sticking point is that the type of the tuple is determined by the value of the `PT` request. The environment *is* what a given request decides to store in it. `interp` doesn't get to choose what's in the tuple, it must come from an index on `PT`. Any attempt to cheat that requirement is going to crash and burn. Now, in a true dependently-typed system we could examine the `PT` value we were given and figure out what `as` should be. Alas, Haskell is not a dependently-typed system.

Comment: Remember, you have access to `(forall s. PT s a)`. In particular, it *can* be instantiated to different types.

Comment: The rank-two type is only useful on the surface of the API. Sooner or later, I have to decide that I'm running my computation in the context of a certain type of tuple with a fixed set of types inside it.

Comment: Also, type level difference lists might be easier to deal with.

Comment: Also, this does not rule out an approach using existential types.

Comment: I don't even want to think about how horrible type-level difference lists would be to work with! Haskell's type language lacks lambdas and partial application, so higher-order representations of data are not going to be fun

Comment: @PyRulez We could attempt to use existential quantification to allow us to grow the tuple in the environment while we interpret the `PT` request. But what would you put inside the existentially-quantified thing? An existentially-quantified `Tuple` is of no use to anyone, so you'd have to wrap it up along with a singleton representation of its list parameter so you can recover the discarded information. But to give a singleton list you have to give singletons for the elements; the tuple would be restricted to things admitting singleton representations (_not_ types of kind `*`).

Comment: Thus the only way to do it would be to restrict yourself to a known finite set of types and use `Elem` as the kinda-sorta-singleton representation of a type of kind `*`. Back to square one.

Comment: What if, instead of `MkRef :: a -> PT s (PTRef s a)`, we had `MkRef :: a -> (PTRef s a -> PT s b) -> PT s b`, and used polymorphic recursion in `interp` (so that the sub-action need not have the same tuple in its `State` type)?

Comment: @DanielWagner I like your idea. I just tried it; unfortunately it didn't work. The problem is that `s` here is `Elem as`. So as long as `s` in the sub-action is tied to same `s` in the return type of `MkRef`, we aren't allowed to vary the list. Again, this'd be tractable if `PT` were indexed by the list itself. The fundamental issue is that the type of the tuple is determined by the value of the `PT`. `interp` doesn't get to choose what `as` is, it has to come from the index of `PT`.

Comment: What if you had a type level doubly ended queue. Then you erase the type information, leaving only a function to get it from one end. You provide a proof that adding things does change elem from the other end. Would this work?

Comment: @PyRulez That _might_ be doable (but certainly not fun) if we could be sure that `PT` was only going to access elements in the same order that it stored them. In general that's not going to be true, and in any case a version of `PT` with such a restriction wouldn't be very useful. (Intuition tells me you might need linear types to implement it anyway.)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Could you make this literate (or provide a link to the code). I think I see a way to finagle it using type classes.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Oh, well, that's easily fixed with `MkRef :: a -> (PTRef s a -> PT (Cons a s) b) -> PT s b` with a suitable `type instance Cons a (Elem as) = Elem (a ': as)` type family...

Comment: @DanielWagner that'd work, and it's slightly more flexible, but I don't see it as a materially different idea. You're indexing the reference by the set of types instead of the monad, but the important part is the type parameter which grows when you add something to the environment. And anyhow you still have to add it into the definition of `PT`.

Comment: @PyRulez As a rule, a program that can't be written with explicit evidence-passing won't be saved by type classes. Type classes are "just" a mechanism for making certain values implicit. A classy program can always be transformed into a program which explicitly passes around dictionaries. Indeed, this is what GHC does during compilation.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson You have two complaints in that comment; one seems to be that my idea is too similar to the existing solution, and the other that it is too different!

Comment: @DanielWagner The existing solution doesn't work! ;)

Comment: Can't you use `do` notation with indexed monads via `RebindableSyntax`?

Answer (score 11):

A simple solution is to wrap a `State` monad and present the same API as `ST`. In this case there's no need to store runtime type information, since it can be determined from the type of `STRef`-s, and the usual `ST s` quantification trick lets us prevent users from messing up the container storing the references.

We keep ref-s in an `IntMap` and increment a counter each time we allocate a new ref. Reading and writing just modifies the `IntMap` with some `unsafeCoerce` sprinkled atop.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, RankNTypes, RoleAnnotations #-}

module PureST (ST, STRef, newSTRef, readSTRef, modifySTRef, runST) where

import Data.IntMap (IntMap, (!))
import qualified Data.IntMap as M

import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import GHC.Prim (Any)
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)

type role ST nominal representational
type role STRef nominal representational
newtype ST s a = ST (State (IntMap Any, Int) a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
newtype STRef s a = STRef Int deriving Show

newSTRef :: a -> ST s (STRef s a)
newSTRef a = ST $ do
  (m, i) <- get
  put (M.insert i (unsafeCoerce a) m, i + 1)
  pure (STRef i)

readSTRef :: STRef s a -> ST s a
readSTRef (STRef i) = ST $ do
  (m, _) <- get
  pure (unsafeCoerce (m ! i))

writeSTRef :: STRef s a -> a -> ST s ()
writeSTRef (STRef i) a = ST $ 
  modify $ \(m, i') -> (M.insert i (unsafeCoerce a) m, i')

modifySTRef :: STRef s a -> (a -> a) -> ST s ()
modifySTRef (STRef i) f = ST $
  modify $ \(m, i') -> (M.adjust (unsafeCoerce f) i m, i')                      

runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
runST (ST s) = evalState s (M.empty, 0)

foo :: Num a => ST s (a, Bool)
foo = do
  a <- newSTRef 0 
  modifySTRef a (+100)
  b <- newSTRef False
  modifySTRef b not
  (,) <$> readSTRef a <*> readSTRef b
```

Now we can do:

```
> runST foo
(100, True)
```

But the following fails with the usual `ST` type error:

```
> runST (newSTRef True)
```

Of course, the above scheme never garbage collects references, instead it frees up everything on each `runST` call. I think a more complex system could implement multiple distinct regions, each tagged by a type parameter, and allocate/free resources in a more fine-grained manner.

Also, the use of `unsafeCoerce` means here that using internals directly is every bit as dangerous as using `GHC.ST` internals and `State#` directly, so we should make sure to present a safe API, and also test our internals thoroughly (or else we may get segfaults in Haskell, a great sin).

Comment: `unsafeCoerce` is cheating!

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Yea, I was thinking that.

Comment: @PyRulez: this should work anywhere with the equivalent of `unsafeCoerce`. The use of `Any` is not  essential here; it's just a bit of a defensive programming thing.

Comment: Also, if we outlaw `unsafeCoerce`, we can still do an indexed state monad with type-level variable contexts and singleton references. It's quite a bit of boilerplate and not as nearly as convenient or performant as the unsafe solution. I could present something like it though if you're interested...

Comment: @AndrásKovács The problem is that both `unsafeCoerce` and `Any` are sort of magical. You could not have either without baking it into the compiler.

Comment: @AndrásKovács I've been hacking away at making that approach work, but I don't think it's possible without indexing `PT` by the set of types in the system. See my forthcoming answer

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson That should be exciting.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Also, if segfaults in Haskell is a great sin, then `unsafeCoerce` is dancin' with the devil.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Since the `s` and `a` in `STRef s a` are phantom types, `coerce` could wreak havoc (which is itself a safe function).

Comment: @PyRulez that's solved by adding role annotations to ST (see my edit).

Comment: @PyRulez The `unsafe` in `unsafeCoerce` is, in some sense, *merely* a reminder that there is a proof burden on the user: namely, that there is a typing property too complicated for the normal type system to understand and it is up to the user to guarantee that the property holds. It should be easy enough to guarantee that property here, assuming the guarantee that the type-checker gives us about `PTRef`s from their interface (namely, that a value of type `PTRef s a` is not given type `PTRef t b` by some other part of the program with `a /~ b`).

Answer (score 10):

Since I posted my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33977814/1523776), you've indicated that you don't mind making changes to your definition of `PT`. I am happy to report: relaxing that restriction changes the answer to your question from **no** to **yes**! I've already argued that you need to index your monad by the set of types in your storage medium, so here's some working code showing how to do that. (I originally had this as an edit to my previous answer but it got too long, so here we are.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Prelude
```

We're going to need a smarter `Monad` class than the one in the Prelude: that of [indexed monad-like things](http://bentnib.org/paramnotions-jfp.pdf) describing paths through a directed graph. For reasons that should become apparent, I'm going to define indexed functors as well.

```
class FunctorIx f where
    imap :: (a -> b) -> f i j a -> f i j b

class FunctorIx m => MonadIx m where
    ireturn :: a -> m i i a
    (>>>=) :: m i j a -> (a -> m j k b) -> m i k b

(>>>) :: MonadIx m => m i j a -> m j k b -> m i k b
ma >>> mb = ma >>>= \_ -> mb

replicateM_ :: MonadIx m => Int -> m i i a -> m i i ()
replicateM_ 0 _ = ireturn ()
replicateM_ n m = m >>> replicateM_ (n - 1) m
```

An indexed monad uses the type system to track the progress of a stateful computation. `m i j a` is a monadic computation which requires an input state of `i`, changes the state to `j`, and produces a value of type `a`. Sequencing indexed monads with `>>>=` is like playing dominoes. You can feed a computation which takes the state from `i` to `j` into a computation which goes from `j` to `k`, and get a bigger computation from `i` to `k`. (There's a richer version of this indexed monad described in [*Kleisli Arrows of Outrageous Fortune*](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Kleisli.pdf) ([and elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28696299/1523776)) but this one is quite enough for our purposes.)

One possibility with `MonadIx` is a `File` monad which tracks the state of a file handle, ensuring you don't forget to free resources. `fOpen :: File Closed Open ()` starts with a closed file and opens it, `fRead :: File Open Open String` returns the contents of an opened file, and `fClose :: File Open Closed ()` takes a file from open to closed. The `run` operation takes a computation of type `File Closed Closed a`, which ensures that your file handles always get cleaned up.

But I digress: here we are concerned not with a file handle but with a set of typed "memory locations"; the types of the things in the virtual machine's memory bank are what we'll use for the monad's indices. I like to get my "program/interpreter" monads [for free](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/242803/103810) because it expresses the fact that results live at the leaves of a computation, and promotes composability and code reuse, so here's the functor which will produce `PT` when we plug it into `FreeIx` below:

```
data PTF ref as bs r where
    MkRef_ :: a -> (ref (a ': as) a -> r) -> PTF ref as (a ': as) r
    GetRef_ :: ref as a -> (a -> r) -> PTF ref as as r
    PutRef_ :: a -> ref as a -> r -> PTF ref as as r

instance FunctorIx (PTF ref) where
    imap f (MkRef_ x next) = MkRef_ x (f . next)
    imap f (GetRef_ ref next) = GetRef_ ref (f . next)
    imap f (PutRef_ x ref next) = PutRef_ x ref (f next)
```

`PTF` is parameterised by the type of reference `ref :: [*] -> * -> *` - references are allowed to know which types are in the system - and indexed by the list of types being stored in the interpreter's "memory". The interesting case is `MkRef_`: making a new reference adds a value of type `a` to the memory, taking `as` to `a ': as`; the continuation expects a `ref` in the extended environment. The other operations don't change the list of types in the system.

When I create references sequentially (`x <- mkRef 1; y <- mkRef 2`), they'll have different types: the first will be a `ref (a ': as) a` and the second will be a `ref (b ': a ': as) b`. To make the types line up, I need a way to use a reference in a bigger environment than the one it was created in. In general, this operation depends on the type of reference, so I'll put it in a class.

```
class Expand ref where
    expand :: ref as a -> ref (b ': as) a
```

One possible generalisation of this class would wrap up the pattern of repeated applications of `expand`, with a type like `inflate :: ref as a -> ref (bs :++: as) a`.

Here's another reusable bit of infrastructure, the *indexed free monad* I mentioned earlier. `FreeIx` turns an indexed functor into an indexed monad by providing a type-aligned joining operation `Free`, which ties the recursive knot in the functor's parameter, and a do-nothing operation `Pure`.

```
data FreeIx f i j a where
    Pure :: a -> FreeIx f i i a
    Free :: f i j (FreeIx f j k a) -> FreeIx f i k a

lift :: FunctorIx f => f i j a -> FreeIx f i j a
lift f = Free (imap Pure f)

instance FunctorIx f => MonadIx (FreeIx f) where
    ireturn = Pure
    Pure x >>>= f = f x
    Free love {- , man -} >>>= f = Free $ imap (>>>= f) love

instance FunctorIx f => FunctorIx (FreeIx f) where
    imap f x = x >>>= (ireturn . f)
```

One disadvantage of free monads is the boilerplate you have to write to make `Free` and `Pure` easier to work with. Here are some single-action `PT`s which form the basis of the monad's API, and some [pattern synonyms](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#pattern-synonyms) to hide the `Free` constructors when we unpack `PT` values.

```
type PT ref = FreeIx (PTF ref)

mkRef :: a -> PT ref as (a ': as) (ref (a ': as) a)
mkRef x = lift $ MkRef_ x id

getRef :: ref as a -> PT ref as as a
getRef ref = lift $ GetRef_ ref id

putRef :: a -> ref as a -> PT ref as as ()
putRef x ref = lift $ PutRef_ x ref ()

pattern MkRef x next = Free (MkRef_ x next)
pattern GetRef ref next = Free (GetRef_ ref next)
pattern PutRef x ref next = Free (PutRef_ x ref next)
```

That's everything we need to be able to write `PT` computations. Here's your `fib` example. I'm using `RebindableSyntax` and locally redefining the monad operators (to their indexed equivalents) so I can use `do` notation on my indexed monad.

```
-- fib adds two Ints to an arbitrary environment
fib :: Expand ref => Int -> PT ref as (Int ': Int ': as) Int
fib n = do
    rold' <- mkRef 0
    rnew <- mkRef 1
    let rold = expand rold'
    replicateM_ n $ do
        old <- getRef rold
        new <- getRef rnew
        putRef new rold
        putRef (old+new) rnew
    getRef rold
        where (>>=) = (>>>=)
              (>>) = (>>>)
              return :: MonadIx m => a -> m i i a
              return = ireturn
              fail :: MonadIx m => String -> m i j a
              fail = error
```

This version of `fib` looks just like the one you wanted to write in the original question. The only difference (apart from the local bindings of `>>=` and so on) is the call to `expand`. Every time you create a new reference, you have to `expand` all the old ones, which is a bit tedious.

Finally we can finish the job we set out to do and build a `PT`-machine which uses a `Tuple` as the storage medium and `Elem` as the reference type.

```
infixr 5 :>
data Tuple as where
    E :: Tuple '[]
    (:>) :: a -> Tuple as -> Tuple (a ': as)

data Elem as a where
    Here :: Elem (a ': as) a
    There :: Elem as a -> Elem (b ': as) a

(!) :: Tuple as -> Elem as a -> a
(x :> xs) ! Here = x
(x :> xs) ! There ix = xs ! ix

updateT :: Elem as a -> a -> Tuple as -> Tuple as
updateT Here x (y :> ys) = x :> ys
updateT (There ix) x (y :> ys) = y :> updateT ix x ys
```

To use an `Elem` in a larger tuple than the one you built it for, you just need to make it look further down the list.

```
instance Expand Elem where
    expand = There
```

Note that this deployment of `Elem` is rather like a de Bruijn index: more-recently-bound variables have smaller indices.

```
interp :: PT Elem as bs a -> Tuple as -> a
interp (MkRef x next) tup = let newTup = x :> tup
                            in interp (next $ Here) newTup
interp (GetRef ix next) tup = let x = tup ! ix
                              in interp (next x) tup
interp (PutRef x ix next) tup = let newTup = updateT ix x tup
                                in interp next newTup
interp (Pure x) tup = x
```

When the interpreter encounters a `MkRef` request, it increases the size of its memory by adding `x` to the front. The type checker will remind you that any `ref`s from before the `MkRef` must be correctly `expand`ed, so existing references don't get out of whack when the tuple changes size. We paid for an interpreter without unsafe casts, but we got referential integrity to boot.

Running from a standing start requires that the `PT` computation expects to begin with an empty memory bank, but we allow it to end in any state.

```
run :: (forall ref. Expand ref => PT ref '[] bs a) -> a
run x = interp x E
```

It typechecks, but does it work?

```
ghci> run (fib 5)
5
ghci> run (fib 3)
2
```

Comment: Huzzah! A win for abstract nonsense! (This provides an interesting foil to András Kovács, I must say.)

Comment: You can use `RebindableSyntax` if you add `fail` to your `MonadIx`. Also, you could use some class magic to implicitly weaken `Elem`-s into extended contexts.

Comment: Anyway, this is roughly what I meant by "indexed state monad" solution. The issue is that this expresses none of the reasons why classic ST works (we could say this is not ST per se, but rather just a specific usage of the indexed state monad). I tried to do a proper embedding of pure ST in Agda, but so far [I've had little success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023712/modeling-st-monad-in-agda).

Comment: FYI, here's [my version](http://lpaste.net/146287) with a bit of magical sugar for `Elem`-s.

Comment: @AndrásKovács "this expresses none of the reasons why classic ST works" <- could you elaborate on what you mean by this? Also, yes, I did write a class to transport an `Elem` to an arbitrarily-larger list, which looked just like your `Weaken`, but I didn't fancy explaining it ;)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson see my Agda SO question that I linked above. In short, the indexed state monad doesn't know or enforce that all our references point to older versions of the same state. Which is one reason why it quickly gets very hard to write code in the indexed state monad that does statically unknown state extensions.

Comment: Can my `PT` be compiled into this `PT`?

Comment: @PyRulez In principle, yes, though I don't know why you'd want to. You'll have to use the usual trick of building something in an existential wrapper (`data APT ref a = forall as bs. APT (PT ref as bs a)`). The hard part would be inserting the right calls to `expand` in the compiled code. When you unwrap and `run` it you'll have to prove `as ~ '[]`. It won't be pretty, and it's a lot more work than just using the indexed version in the first place with `RebindableSyntax`.