# Modeling the ST monad in Agda

Tags: haskell, agda, st-monad

This recent [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975270/can-a-st-like-monad-be-executed-purely-without-the-st-library) prompted me to write an unsafe and pure emulation of the ST monad in Haskell, a slightly modified version of which you can see below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import GHC.Prim (Any)
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)
import Data.List

newtype ST s a = ST (State ([Any], Int) a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
newtype STRef s a = STRef Int deriving Show

newSTRef :: a -> ST s (STRef s a)
newSTRef a = ST $ do
  (env, i) <- get
  put (unsafeCoerce a : env, i + 1)
  pure (STRef i)

update :: [a] -> (a -> a) -> Int -> [a]
update as f i = case splitAt i as of
  (as, b:bs) -> as ++ f b : bs
  _          -> as

readSTRef :: STRef s a -> ST s a
readSTRef (STRef i) = ST $ do
  (m, i') <- get
  pure (unsafeCoerce (m !! (i' - i - 1)))

modifySTRef :: STRef s a -> (a -> a) -> ST s ()
modifySTRef (STRef i) f = ST $
  modify $ \(env, i') -> (update env (unsafeCoerce f) (i' - i - 1), i')

runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
runST (ST s) = evalState s ([], 0)
```

It would be good if we could present the usual ST monad API without `unsafeCoerce`. Specifically, I'd like to formalize the reasons why the usual GHC ST monad and the above emulation works. It seems to me that they work because:

- Any `STRef s a` with the right `s` tag *must have been* created in the current ST computation, since `runST` ensures that different states can't be mixed up.
- The previous point together with the fact that ST computations can only ever extend the environment of references implies that any `STRef s a` with the right `s` tag refers to a valid `a`-typed location in the environment (after possibly weakening the reference at runtime).

The above points enable a remarkably proof-obligation-free programming experience. Nothing really comes close in safe and pure Haskell that I can think of; we can do a rather poor imitation with indexed state monads and heterogeneous lists, but that doesn't express any of the above points and thus requires proofs at each use site of `STRef`-s.

I'm at a loss how we could formalize this properly in Agda. For starters, "allocated in *this* computation" is tricky enough. I thought about representing `STRef`-s as proofs that a particular allocation is contained in a particular `ST` computation, but that seems to result in an endless recursion of type indexing.

Comment: You might want to look at Bernardy et al, "Proofs for Free", which considers parametricity in Agda. Apparently, adding a parametricity postulate does not change the consistency strength. But even if you don't want to do that, the paper may give you some ideas.

Comment: Don't you just want a global state extendable with unique names? Linear types, nominal logics, another `State` on top of the existing... I'd stick to the indexed `State` monad as in one of the answers to the mentioned SO question. Also, there is a very similar construction in the Wouter Swiestra's [thesis](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~swier004/Publications/Thesis.pdf) (note that now we have instance arguments to which we can delegate the proving work (I haven't tried this though)).

Comment: @user3237465 I'd like to have some notion of "older/newer version of the same state". With indexed state monads, we have to prove each time that a reference can be weakened to the possibly extended new state. There's no necessary relation between the state in which we allocate a ref and the state in which we use it. Which is justified, I guess, since references can come from anywhere in the absence of `runST` tricks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some form of a solution done by postulating a parametricity theorem.
It also ensures that the postulate does not get in the way of computation.

http://code.haskell.org/~Saizan/ST/ST.agda

"darcs get http://code.haskell.org/~Saizan/ST/" for the full source

I'm not happy about the closed universe of types but it's the easy way to tailor the parametricity theorem to what we actually need.

Comment: Thanks. I get the main idea, but this'll require some effort to digest.

Comment: The link is now dead. Is there an up to date version?

Comment: @WorldSEnder: here's a hopefully [persistent link](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/misc-stuff/blob/2e72234ea7d9d6c51063732ee61b2929ce00ee08/agda/ST/ST.agda) to a comparable Agda file.