# Type-safe Flow (State Machine)

Tags: haskell, gadt

I am trying to create a type-safe Question-Answer flow in Haskell. I am modeling QnA as a directed graph, similar to a FSM.

Each node in the graph represent a question:

```
data Node s a s' = Node {
  question :: Question a,
  process :: s -> a -> s'
}
```

`s` is the input state, `a` is the answer to the question and `s'` is the output state. Nodes depend on the input state `s`, meaning that for processing the answer we have to be a in a particular state before.

`Question a` represent a simple question / answer producing an answer of type `a`.

By type-safe I mean, for example given a node `Node2 :: si -> a -> s2`, if `si` depends on `s1` then all the paths ending with `Node2` must be passing through a node that produces `s1` first. (If `s1 == si` then all predecessors of `Node2`  must be producing `s1`).

**An Example**

QnA: In an online shopping website, we need to ask user's body size and favorite color.

1. `e1`: ask user if they know their size. If yes then go to `e2` otherwise go to `e3`
2. `e2`: ask user's size and go to `ef` to ask the color.
3. `e3`: (user doesn't know their size), ask user's weight and go to `e4`.
4. `e4`: (after `e3`) ask user's height and calculate their size and go to `ef.`
5. `ef`: ask user's favorite color and finish the flow with the `Final` result.

In my model, `Edge`s connect `Node`s to each other:

```
data Edge s sf where
  Edge  :: EdgeId -> Node s a s' -> (s' -> a -> Edge s' sf) -> Edge s sf
  Final :: EdgeId -> Node s a s' -> (s' -> a -> sf) -> Edge s sf
```

`sf` is the final result of the QnA, that here is: `(Bool, Size, Color)`.

The QnA state at each moment can be represented by a tuple: `(s, EdgeId)`. This state is serializable and we should be able to continue a QnA by just knowing this state.

```
saveState :: (Show s) => (s, Edge s sf) -> String
saveState (s, Edge eid n _) = show (s, eid)

getEdge :: EdgeId -> Edge s sf
getEdge = undefined --TODO

respond :: s -> Edge s sf -> Input -> Either sf (s', Edge s' sf)
respond s (Edge ...) input = Right (s', Edge ...)
respond s (Final ...) input = Left s' -- Final state

-- state = serialized (s, EdgeId)
-- input = user's answer to the current question
main' :: String -> Input -> Either sf (s', Edge s' sf)
main' state input =
  let (s, eid) = read state :: ((), EdgeId) --TODO
      edge = getEdge eid
  in respond s input edge
```

[image: Flow for determining user's dress size]

Full code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes, TupleSections #-}

type Input = String
type Prompt = String
type Color = String
type Size = Int
type Weight = Int
type Height = Int

data Question a = Question {
  prompt :: Prompt,
  answer :: Input -> a
}

-- some questions 
doYouKnowYourSizeQ :: Question Bool
doYouKnowYourSizeQ = Question "Do you know your size?" read

whatIsYourSizeQ :: Question Size
whatIsYourSizeQ = Question "What is your size?" read

whatIsYourWeightQ :: Question Weight
whatIsYourWeightQ = Question "What is your weight?" read

whatIsYourHeightQ :: Question Height
whatIsYourHeightQ = Question "What is your height?" read

whatIsYourFavColorQ :: Question Color
whatIsYourFavColorQ = Question "What is your fav color?" id

-- Node and Edge

data Node s a s' = Node {
  question :: Question a,
  process :: s -> a -> s'
}

data Edge s sf where
  Edge  :: EdgeId -> Node s a s' -> (s' -> a -> Edge s' sf) -> Edge s sf
  Final :: EdgeId -> Node s a s' -> (s' -> a -> sf) -> Edge s sf

data EdgeId = E1 | E2 | E3 | E4 | Ef deriving (Read, Show)

-- nodes

n1 :: Node () Bool Bool
n1 = Node doYouKnowYourSizeQ (const id)

n2 :: Node Bool Size (Bool, Size)
n2 = Node whatIsYourSizeQ (,)

n3 :: Node Bool Weight (Bool, Weight)
n3 = Node whatIsYourWeightQ (,)

n4 :: Node (Bool, Weight) Height (Bool, Size)
n4 = Node whatIsYourHeightQ (\ (b, w) h -> (b, w * h))

n5 :: Node (Bool, Size) Color (Bool, Size, Color)
n5 = Node whatIsYourFavColorQ (\ (b, i) c -> (b, i, c))


-- type-safe edges

e1 = Edge E1 n1 (const $ \ b -> if b then e2 else e3)
e2 = Edge E2 n2 (const $ const ef)
e3 = Edge E3 n3 (const $ const e4)
e4 = Edge E4 n4 (const $ const ef)
ef = Final Ef n5 const


ask :: Edge s sf -> Prompt
ask (Edge _ n _) = prompt $ question n
ask (Final _ n _) = prompt $ question n

respond :: s -> Edge s sf -> Input -> Either sf (s', Edge s' sf)
respond s (Edge _ n f) i =
  let a  = (answer $ question n) i
      s' = process n s a
      n' = f s' a
  in Right undefined --TODO n'

respond s (Final _ n f) i =
  let a  = (answer $ question n) i
      s' = process n s a
  in Left undefined --TODO s'


-- User Interaction:

saveState :: (Show s) => (s, Edge s sf) -> String
saveState (s, Edge eid n _) = show (s, eid)

getEdge :: EdgeId -> Edge s sf
getEdge = undefined --TODO

-- state = serialized (s, EdgeId) (where getEdge :: EdgeId -> Edge s sf)
-- input = user's answer to the current question
main' :: String -> Input -> Either sf (s', Edge s' sf)
main' state input =
  let (s, eid) = undefined -- read state --TODO
      edge = getEdge eid
  in respond s edge input
```

It's important for me to keep the edges type-safe. Meaning for instance incorrectly linking `e2` to `e3` must be a type error: `e2 = Edge E2 n2 (const $ const ef)` is fine by `e2 = Edge E2 n2 (const $ const e3)` must be an error.

I have indicated my questions with `--TOOD`:

- Given my criteria for keeping edges type-safe, `Edge s sf` must have an input type variable (`s`) then how can I create `getEdge :: EdgeId -> Edge s sf` function?
- How can I create the `respond` function that given the current state `s` and current edge `Edge s sf`, will return either the final state (if current edge is `Final`) or the next state and the next edge `(s', Edge s' sf)`?

My design of `Node s a s'` and `Edge s sf` might be simply wrong. I don't have to stick with it.

Comment: Your datatype contains arbitrary function types - which you cannot serialize - so you cannot hope to get the interface you want here. `saveState` is useless w/o the ability to serialize the graph itself. The first step is to identify what you actually wish to model - the only functions you use in an 'edge' function are the constant function and `if`, and if this is representative if your general use case, then modelling this will probably be quite easy. If you really want to model a 'graph' (nodes & edges) with the additional type safety constraints then this is tougher.

Comment: I am looking for a general solution. I can imagine more complex `Edge`s that select the next subgraph depending on the current state `s` and latest answer `a`. A real life `Edge` might even use database connections etc. and return the subgraph in an `IO (Edge s' sf)`.

Comment: One does not 'select' which node to 'go to' in a graph - each node is simply connected to a (possibly empty) set of nodes. The *value semantics* of a node somehow 'producing' a value on which to transition, and the transition itself, are not part of the graph structure - rather you simply have a graph whose nodes and edges are labelled by things which you interpret (in your domain) to be 'states' and 'transitions'. i.e. your *edge* is `e1 = Edge n1 [n2,n3]` but your *edge label* is the function `\b -> if b ...` - the *shape* of this graph can be serialized easily even if the labels cannot.

Comment: In `e1 = Edge n1 [n2,n3]` `n2` and `n3` may not be of the same type, they have same input but different outputs. (but `n1 >>>= n2 >>>= nf` and `n1 >>>= n3 >>>= n4 >>>= nf` are of the same type with same input and output).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the purposes of having a simple example to explain, I'm going to show you a solution which doesn't have natural support for suspending, persisting and resuming computations. At the end I'll give you the gist of how to add that in - hopefully you'll be able to figure out the nitty gritty of it yourself.

---

Here's the so-called *indexed state monad*:

```
newtype IStateT m i o a = IStateT { runIState :: i -> m (o, a) }
```

`IStateT` is like a regular state monad transformer, except that the type of the implicit state is allowed to change throughout the course of a computation. Sequencing actions in the indexed state monad requires that the output state of one action matches the input state of the next. This sort of domino-like sequencing is what [Atkey's *parameterised monad*](http://bentnib.org/paramnotions-jfp.pdf) (or [*indexed monad*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690448/what-is-indexed-monad)) is for.

```
class IMonad m where
    ireturn :: a -> m i i a
    (>>>=) :: m i j a -> (a -> m j k b) -> m i k b

(>>>) :: IMonad m => m i j a -> m j k b -> m i k b
mx >>> my = mx >>>= \_ -> my
```

`IMonad` is the class of monad-like things which describe a path through an indexed graph. The type of `(>>>=)` says "If you have a computation which goes from `i` to `j` and a computation from `j` to `k`, I can join them up to give you a computation from `i` to `k`".

We'll also need to lift computations from classical monads into indexed monads:

```
class IMonadTrans t where
    ilift :: Monad m => m a -> t m i i a
```

Note that the code for `IStateT` is just the same as the code for the regular state monad - it's just the types that have got smarter.

```
iget :: Monad m => IStateT m s s s
iget = IStateT $ \s -> return (s, s)

iput :: Monad m => o -> IStateT m i o ()
iput x = IStateT $ \_ -> return (x, ())

imodify :: Monad m => (i -> o) -> IStateT m i o ()
imodify f = IStateT $ \s -> return (f s, ())

instance Monad m => IMonad (IStateT m) where
    ireturn x = IStateT (\s -> return (s, x))
    IStateT f >>>= g = IStateT $ \s -> do
                                    (s', x) <- f s
                                    let IStateT h = g x
                                    h s'
instance IMonadTrans IStateT where
    ilift m = IStateT $ \s -> m >>= \x -> return (s, x)
```

The idea is that monadic actions like `askSize` and `askWeight` (below) will *add some data to the implicit environment*, growing its type. So I'm going to build the implicit environment out of nested tuples, treating them as type-level lists of types. Nested tuples are more flexible (though less efficient) than flat tuples, because they allow you to abstract over the tail of the list. This allows you to build tuples of arbitrary size.

```
type StateMachine = IStateT IO

newtype Size = Size Int
newtype Height = Height Int
newtype Weight = Weight Int
newtype Colour = Colour String

-- askSize takes an environment of type as and adds a Size element
askSize :: StateMachine as (Size, as) ()
askSize = askNumber "What is your size?" Size

-- askHeight takes an environment of type as and adds a Height element
askHeight :: StateMachine as (Height, as) ()
askHeight = askNumber "What is your height?" Height

-- etc
askWeight :: StateMachine as (Weight, as) ()
askWeight = askNumber "What is your weight?" Weight

askColour :: StateMachine as (Colour, as) ()
askColour =
    -- poor man's do-notation. You could use RebindableSyntax
    ilift (putStrLn "What is your favourite colour?") >>>
    ilift readLn                                      >>>= \answer ->
    imodify (Colour answer,)

calculateSize :: Height -> Weight -> Size
calculateSize (Height h) (Weight w) = Size (h - w)  -- or whatever the calculation is

askNumber :: String -> (Int -> a) -> StateMachine as (a, as) ()
askNumber question mk =
    ilift (putStrLn question) >>>
    ilift readLn              >>>= \answer ->
    case reads answer of
        [(x, _)] -> imodify (mk x,)
        _ -> ilift (putStrLn "Please type a number") >>> askNumber question mk

askYN :: String -> StateMachine as as Bool
askYN question =
    ilift (putStrLn question) >>>
    ilift readLn              >>>= \answer ->
    case answer of
        "y" -> ireturn True
        "n" -> ireturn False
        _ -> ilift (putStrLn "Please type y or n") >>> askYN question
```

My implementation differs from your specification slightly. You say it should be *impossible* to ask for the user's size and then ask for their weight. I say it should be possible - the result just won't necessarily have the type you wanted (because you've added two things to the environment, not one). This comes in useful here, where `askOrCalculateSize` is just a black box which adds a `Size` (and nothing else) to an environment. Sometimes it does it by asking for the size directly; sometimes it calculates it by first asking for the height and the weight. It doesn't matter as far as the type-checker is concerned.

```
interaction :: StateMachine xs (Colour, (Size, xs)) ()
interaction =
    askYN "Do you know your size?" >>>= \answer ->
    askOrCalculateSize answer >>>
    askColour

    where askOrCalculateSize True = askSize
          askOrCalculateSize False =
            askWeight >>>
            askHeight >>>
            imodify (\(h, (w, xs)) -> ((calculateSize h w), xs))
```

---

There's a question remaining: how can one *resume* a computation from a persisted state? You don't statically know the type of the input environment (though it's safe to assume the output is always `(Colour, Size)`) because it varies throughout the computation, and you don't know until you load the persisted state where it was up to.

The trick is to use a bit of GADT evidence which you can pattern-match on to *learn* what the type was. `Stage` represents where you could've got up to in the process, and it's indexed by the type that the environment should have by that stage. `Suspended` pairs up a `Stage` with the actual data that was in the environment at the point that the computation was suspended.

```
data Stage as where
    AskSize :: Stage as
    AskWeight :: Stage as
    AskHeight :: Stage (Weight, as)
    AskColour :: Stage (Size, as)

data Suspended where
    Suspended :: Stage as -> as -> Suspended

resume :: Suspended -> StateMachine as (Colour, (Size, as)) ()
resume (Suspended AskSize e) =
    iput e                                               >>>
    askSize                                              >>>
    askColour
resume (Suspended AskWeight e) =
    iput e                                               >>>
    askWeight                                            >>>
    askHeight                                            >>>
    imodify (\(h, (w, xs)) -> ((calculateSize h w), xs)) >>>
    askColour
resume (Suspended AskHeight e) =
    iput e                                               >>>
    askHeight                                            >>>
    imodify (\(h, (w, xs)) -> ((calculateSize h w), xs)) >>>
    askColour
resume (Suspended AskColour e) =
    iput e                                               >>>
    askColour
```

Now you can add suspension points to the computation:

```
-- given persist :: Suspended -> IO ()
suspend :: Stage as -> StateMachine as as ()
suspend stage =
    iget                                  >>>= \env
    ilift (persist (Suspended stage env))
```

`resume` works, but it's pretty ugly and has a lot of code duplication. This is because once you've put a state monad together you can't take it apart again to look inside it. You can't jump in at a given point in the computation. This is the big advantage of your original design, wherein you represented the state machine as a data structure which can be queried in order to figure out how to resume the computation. This is called an *initial* encoding, whereas my example (representing the state machine as a function) is a *final* encoding. Final encodings are simple but initial encodings are flexible. Hopefully you can see how to adapt an initial approach to the indexed monad design.

Comment: Indexed state monad is a brilliant solution. How can I cast my current state to `Stage`?

Comment: Is this in the right direction? `interaction' machine stage as = (\ (r, _) -> Suspended stage r) <$> runIState machine as`

Comment: I was thinking that you'd insert calls to `suspend` in your monadic computation directly.

Comment: OK, I see `(suspend AskWeight >>> askWeight) >>> ...`

Comment: @homam Exactly.

Comment: We can easily reduce duplication by recursively calling `resume`: `resume (Suspended AskWeight e) = iput e >>> askWeight >>> iget >>>= (resume . Suspended AskHeight)`

Comment: @homam, to represent your computation more explicitly (if that's something you want to do), take a look at "Reflection Without Remorse" and its associated type-aligned sequences. That describes the "initial encoding" Benjamin Hodgson mentioned.

Comment: After each question, I want to terminate the flow before user input. Is it the right approach to change the state to `Maybe`, for example: `askColour :: StateMachine as (Maybe Colour, as) ()` and `askColour = ilift (...) >>> imodify (Nothing, )`? I will also introduce an answer function: `answer :: String -> Suspended -> StateMachine as FinalResult ()`