# Can a Haskell type constructor have non-type parameters?

Tags: haskell, types

A type constructor produces a type given a type. For example, the Maybe constructor

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

could be a given a concrete type, like Char, and give a concrete type, like Maybe Char. In terms of kinds, one has

```
GHCI> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
```

My question: Is it possible to define a type constructor that yields a concrete type given a *Char*, say? Put another way, is it possible to mix *kinds* and *types* in the type signature of a type constructor? Something like

```
GHCI> :k my_type
my_type :: Char -> * -> *
```

Comment: Yes. These days, types and kinds are pretty much the same thing.

Comment: You can declare a type constructor with kind `Char -> ...` but there are no types which inhabit the kind `Char`, because `data Char = C# Char#` and primitive types are not promotable.

Comment: Have you looked at GADT's?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can a Haskell type constructor have non-type parameters?

Let's unpack what you mean by *type parameter*. The word *type* has (at least) two potential meanings: do you mean *type* in the narrow sense of *things of kind `*`*, or in the broader sense of *things at the type level*? We can't (yet) use values in types, but modern GHC features a very rich kind language, allowing us to use a wide range of things other than concrete types as type parameters.

### Higher-Kinded Types

Type constructors in Haskell have always admitted non-`*` parameters. For example, the encoding of the fixed point of a functor works in plain old Haskell 98:

```
newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }

ghci> :k Fix
Fix :: (* -> *) -> *
```

`Fix` is parameterised by a functor of kind `* -> *`, not a type of kind `*`.

### Beyond `*` and `->`

The `DataKinds` extension enriches GHC's kind system with user-declared kinds, so kinds may be built of pieces other than `*` and `->`. It works by *promoting* all `data` declarations to the kind level. That is to say, a `data` declaration like

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat  -- natural numbers
```

introduces a *kind* `Nat` and *type* constructors `Z :: Nat` and `S :: Nat -> Nat`, as well as the usual type and value constructors. This allows you to write datatypes parameterised by type-level data, such as the customary *vector* type, which is a linked list indexed by its length.

```
data Vec n a where
    Nil :: Vec Z a
    (:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a

ghci> :k Vec
Vec :: Nat -> * -> *
```

There's a related extension called `ConstraintKinds`, which frees constraints like `Ord a` from the yoke of the "fat arrow" `=>`, allowing them to roam across the landscape of the type system as nature intended. Kmett has used this power to build a [category of constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.8/docs/Data-Constraint.html), with the newtype `(:-) :: Constraint -> Constraint -> *` denoting "entailment": a value of type `c :- d` is a proof that if `c` holds then `d` also holds. For example, we can prove that `Ord a` implies `Eq [a]` for all `a`:

```
ordToEqList :: Ord a :- Eq [a]
ordToEqList = Sub Dict
```

### Life after `forall`

However, Haskell currently maintains a strict separation between the type level and the value level. Things at the type level are always erased before the program runs, (almost) always inferrable, invisible in expressions, and (dependently) quantified by `forall`. If your application requires something more flexible, such as dependent quantification over runtime data, then you have to manually simulate it using a *singleton* encoding.

For example, the specification of `split` says it chops a vector at a certain length according to its (runtime!) argument. The *type* of the output vector depends on the *value* of `split`'s argument. We'd like to write this...

```
split :: (n :: Nat) -> Vec (n :+: m) a -> (Vec n a, Vec m a)
```

... where I'm using the type function `(:+:) :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat`, which stands for addition of type-level naturals, to ensure that the input vector is at least as long as `n`...

```
type family n :+: m where
    Z :+: m = m
    S n :+: m = S (n :+: m)
```

... but Haskell won't allow that declaration of `split`! There aren't any values of type `Z` or `S n`; only types of kind `*` contain values. We can't access `n` at runtime directly, but we can use a GADT which we can pattern-match on to *learn* what the type-level `n` is:

```
data Natty n where
    Zy :: Natty Z
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (S n)

ghci> :k Natty
Natty :: Nat -> *
```

`Natty` is called a *singleton*, because for a given (well-defined) `n` there is only one (well-defined) value of type `Natty n`. We can use `Natty n` as a run-time stand-in for `n`.

```
split :: Natty n -> Vec (n :+: m) a -> (Vec n a, Vec m a)
split Zy xs = (Nil, xs)
split (Sy n) (x :> xs) =
    let (ys, zs) = split n xs
    in (x :> ys, zs)
```

Anyway, the point is that values - runtime data - can't appear in types. It's pretty tedious to duplicate the definition of `Nat` in singleton form (and things get worse if you want the compiler to infer such values); dependently-typed languages like Agda, Idris, or a future Haskell escape the tyranny of strictly separating types from values and give us a range of expressive quantifiers. You're able to use an honest-to-goodness `Nat` as `split`'s runtime argument and mention its value dependently in the return type.

@pigworker has written extensively about the unsuitability of Haskell's strict separation between types and values for modern dependently-typed programming. See, for example, [the *Hasochism* paper](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf), or his [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ad4BVmPni7A) on the unexamined assumptions that have been drummed into us by four decades of Hindley-Milner-style programming.

### Dependent Kinds

Finally, for what it's worth, with `TypeInType` modern GHC unifies types and kinds, allowing us to talk about kind variables using the same tools that we use to talk about type variables. In [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40468548/1523776) about session types I made use of `TypeInType` to define a kind for tagged type-level sequences of types:

```
infixr 5 :!, :?
data Session = Type :! Session  -- Type is a synonym for *
             | Type :? Session
             | E
```

Comment: The DataKinds extension, the TypeInType project, the notion of a singleton type, and the notion of a dependently-typed language all address my question. I'll be looking into these things, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at using Generalized Algebraic Data Types (GADTS), which enable you to define concrete outputs based on input type, e.g.

```
data CustomMaybe a where
  MaybeChar :: Maybe a -> CustomMaybe Char
  MaybeString :: Maybe a > CustomMaybe String
  MaybeBool :: Maybe a -> CustomMaybe Bool

exampleFunction :: CustomMaybe a -> a
exampleFunction (MaybeChar maybe) = 'e' 
exampleFunction (MaybeString maybe) = True //Compile error

main = do 
  print $ exampleFunction (MaybeChar $ Just 10)
```

To a similar effect, RankNTypes can allow the implementation of similar behaviour:

```
exampleFunctionOne :: a -> a
exampleFunctionOne el = el

type PolyType = forall a. a -> a

exampleFuntionTwo :: PolyType -> Int
exampleFunctionTwo func = func 20
exampleFunctionTwo func = func "Hello" --Compiler error, PolyType being forced to return 'Int'

main = do
  print $ exampleFunctionTwo exampleFunctionOne
```

The PolyType definition allows you to insert the polymorphic function within exampleFunctionTwo and force its output to be 'Int'.

Comment: This doesn't really give what I wanted in my question, but I didn't know of it and it was a neat thing to learn about. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend @Benjamin Hodgson's answer and the references he gives to see how to make this sort of thing *useful*.  But, to answer your question more directly, using several extensions (`DataKinds`, `KindSignatures`, and `GADTs`), you can define types that are parameterized on (certain) concrete types.

For example, here's one parameterized on the concrete `Bool` datatype:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module FlaggedType where

-- The single quotes below are optional.  They serve to notify
-- GHC that we are using the type-level constructors lifted from
-- data constructors rather than types of the same name (and are
-- only necessary where there's some kind of ambiguity otherwise).
data Flagged :: Bool -> * -> * where
  Truish  :: a -> Flagged 'True a
  Falsish :: a -> Flagged 'False a

-- separate instances, just as if they were different types
-- (which they are)
instance (Show a) => Show (Flagged 'False a) where
  show (Falsish x) = show x
instance (Show a) => Show (Flagged 'True a) where
  show (Truish x) = show x ++ "*"

-- these lists have types as indicated
x = [Truish 1, Truish 2, Truish 3]           -- :: Flagged 'True Integer
y = [Falsish "a", Falsish "b", Falsish "c"]  -- :: Flagged 'False String

-- this won't typecheck: it's just like [1,2,"abc"]
z = [Truish 1, Truish 2, Falsish 3]          -- won't typecheck
```

Note that this isn't much different from defining two completely separate types:

```
data FlaggedTrue a = Truish a
data FlaggedFalse a = Falsish a
```

In fact, I'm hard pressed to think of any advantage `Flagged` has over defining two separate types, except if you have a bar bet with someone that you can write useful Haskell code without type classes.  For example, you can write:

```
getInt :: Flagged a Int -> Int
getInt (Truish z) = z    -- same polymorphic function...
getInt (Falsish z) = z   -- ...defined on two separate types
```

Maybe someone else can think of some other advantages.

Anyway, I believe that parameterizing types with concrete values really only becomes useful when the concrete type is sufficient "rich" that you can use it to leverage the type checker, as in Benjamin's examples.

As @user2407038 noted, most interesting primitive types, like `Int`s, `Char`s, `String`s and so on *can't* be used this way.  Interestingly enough, though, you *can* use literal positive integers and strings as type parameters, but they are treated as `Nat`s and `Symbol`s (as defined in `GHC.TypeLits`) respectively.

So something like this is possible:

```
import GHC.TypeLits
data Tagged :: Symbol -> Nat -> *  -> * where
    One :: a -> Tagged "one" 1 a
    Two :: a -> Tagged "two" 2 a
    Three :: a -> Tagged "three" 3 a
```

Comment: The advantage over two separate data types only comes in if you have other things of kind `Bool` floating around.  Then you can write functions of type `Flagged b a -> Flogged b`, which would otherwise require defining a type family to convert between the two representations.

Comment: The reason type-level Booleans usually aren't very useful is because people tend to use them as a stand-in for the information they're actually interested in. Erasing such information to a single bit means you have to reconstruct it by hand. If I had a pound for every Stack Overflow question where the root cause of the problem was inappropriate use of type-level Booleans...

Answer (score 0):

No. Haskell doesn't have dependent types (yet). See https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2016/07/24/dependent-types-in-haskell-progress-report/ for some discussion of when it may.

In the meantime, you can get behavior like this in Agda, Idris, and Cayenne.

Comment: Check again. You may find things have changed.

Comment: [this is the first entry](https://wiki.haskell.org/Dependent_type) for a google search on 'Haskell dependent types'

Comment: `data MyType c a where MkMyType :: a -> MyType 'x' a` (or maybe it needs to be `''x'`, don't have my compy to try) has precisely the desired kind.  While it's true that Haskell doesn't have full dependent types, I don't think "No" is the correct answer.