# A MonadTransformer to typecheck for a completed action

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

**Preamble**

This is one of those questions where I think that someone has already solved my problem, but I don't know where to look.

**Question**

I am looking for a MonadTransformer that carries the idea of being complete or incomplete in such a way that an action of the monad stack will fail to typecheck unless it is complete.

**My Situation**

I have a Monad stack with a state which holds an MVar.  Failing to write to this MVar will cause a `thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar` exception. I could just check the MVar itself, but handing it off to another thread (which follows the same rules) is also a valid way to get the MVar filled (as is throwing an error).

I am seeking some way for the typechecker to throw an error if one of those conditions is not met by the time the monad is run.  I can check at run time but, I think there might be a way to use the type system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like some kind of [indexed monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690448/what-is-indexed-monad) could help. Indexed monads allow or forbid some operations according to some type-level state.

---

We could also rely on polymorphism:

```
{-# language RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

-- Receives an v and returns a "proof" token
newtype Gulp token v = Gulp (v -> IO token)

-- Computation polymorphic on the token
type EnsuredWrite v r = forall token. StateT (Gulp token v) IO (token,r)
```

The idea is that actions of type `EnsuredWrite` need to return a `token` value, but only know how to produce one by feeding the function in `Gulp`. If they return at all, they must have called that function.

The actual type of the token is not important, it can be a simple `()`. But `EnsuredWrite` actions shouldn't know that, hence the `forall`.

This solution doesn't forbid repeated writes, though.