# Impose constraint on MonadIO return type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, typeclass, monad-transformers

I'm trying to make an instance of `MonadIO` for a type that represents computations in the cloud. So `liftIO` would represent an `IO` action that is executed locally.

[transient-universe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transient-universe-0.4.6.1/docs/Transient-Move.html#t:Cloud), the library that provides this, provides a function `localIO` that does exactly this. But it is not composable in some other library that could embed any other `MonadIO`.

The problem is, that `localIO` requires the return type of the `IO` action to be an instance of `Read`, `Show` and `Typeable`. Whereas `MonadIO` doesn't contemplate this case:

```
class MonadIO m where
    liftIO :: IO a -> m a
```

In my case, I'd need to write another type class, that does it:

```
class RestrictableMonadIO (m a) where
    liftRestrictedIO :: IO a -> m a
```

So it would allow me to do this:

```
instance (Read a, Show a, Typeable a) => MonadIO (Cloud a) where
    liftRestrictedIO = localIO
```

Is there a way of doing this without having to declare my own typeclass?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It is well-known that the standard functor, monad etc. classes don't cope well with additional constraints. `Data.Set` should be a functor, but it is not because of the `Ord` constraint, for instance. Some more advanced classes have been proposed, like indexed monads, to address this issue, but they never became really popular.

Comment: @chi Can you elaborate on indexed monads being used to add extra class constraints?

Comment: @gallais `class IxMonad m a b where (>>=) :: m a -> (a->m b) -> m b` allows for `instance IxMonad [] a b` and `instance (Ord a, Ord b) => IxMonad Data.Set a b`. Or, `class CMonad m (c :: * -> Constraint) where (>>=) :: (c a, c b) => ...` allows for an additional constraint. (I am probably using the term "indexed monad" here a bit loosely, but you get the idea)

Comment: Oh okay, so not [indexed monads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690448/what-is-indexed-monad)? Your definition looks pretty dodgy though: you'd be able to give different instances for e.g. `IxMonad m Int a` and `IxMonad m Integer a`, etc. You give up on the "uniformity" of the effect handling.

Comment: @gallais I agree, I was fetching terms from memory and got it wrong. [Restricted monad](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/RestrictedMonad.lhs) is probably a better term.  I'm unsure if the real indexed monads can be used for this, I'd guess they can't. `CMonad` should be a bit more uniform, though.

Comment: Yeah `CMonad` looks good.

Comment: @chi, I don't know if it's fair to say that "they never became really popular." Idris has incorporated some of those ideas as part of the language. I don't know that they did quite the right thing there, but I think it demonstrates that people really want these things. Balancing power against syntactic convenience is not so easy, and Haskell tends to be somewhat conservative about syntax. I think given a bit more time we may yet see these ideas rise to more prominence.

Comment: @dfeuer Probably it is a bit unfair -- still, in the vast majority of Hackage packages we can find monads/applicatives/etc. instead of their indexed/restricted generalizations. More concretely, what I wanted to say is that, until such generalizations become the "default" choice in the Haskell package ecosystem, even if one defined a proper instance there is (unfortunately) little chance that said instance will interact with existing libraries, which instead only consider the regular monads/etc. In the future, this might change, of course.

Comment: @chi, yes, very fair. I just don't want people to give up on these ideas just because they're not *yet* very popular. Especially since the machinery to support them keeps improving, slowly.